# How to split a string with , in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on webapi actually I need to split a string here I am getting data from controlers  from data I had separated data like Menus and subMenus.

Like I am getting data

```
  MenuName:  "Home" "product" "setting" "orders" "contact " "Profile"

  SubMenus for Product: 
                       "viewProduct,Addproduct,searchProduct";
```

Here I need to split the submenus but the menus are not splitted. I don't know what's  wrong.

Here is my code:

```
var Url = "/api/MenuItem";
(function($) {
    $.buildMenu = function(MenuId, CurrentPage) {
        $.getJSON(Url, function(data) {
            alert(data);
            var item = data;
            $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                var MenuItems = [];
                MenuItems = v.MenuName;
                alert(MenuItems);

                var subitems = [];
                subitems = v.SubMenUs;
                alert(subitems);

                var spltting = [];
                var splitteditems = [];
                spltting = subitems[0];
                splitteditems = spltting.split(',');
                alert(spltting.count());
                alert(spltting.toString());
                var count = new Array();
                for (var n = 0; n < splitteditems.length; n++) {
                    count.push(parseInt(splitteditems[n]));
                }
            });
            alert(item.toString());
            $('.' + MenuId).append("<ul>");

            for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                if (CurrentPage == item[i].MenuName)
                    $('.' + MenuId).append("<li><a class='main_menu_active'>" +
                        item[i].MenuName + "</a></li>"
                    );
                else
                    $('.' + MenuId).append("<li> " +
                        item[i].MenuName + "</li>"
                    );
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);​
```

I need to split the subMenus and need to append to nested list.

Comment: This question might be better phrased "how to split a string in Javascript"...

Comment: `spltting = subitems[0];
splitteditems = spltting.split(',');` is `subitems` a string or an array?

Comment: thank it is working thank you for u to spent time for me thankalot friends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*jQuery is JavaScript*, so this can be accomplished using the JavaScript `String.split(",")` method.

Comment: No i had tried but still it is not working Mr Namida Aneskansm and thank there is any other any way for it plz

Comment: Are you sure that the issue lies in the splitting? What kind of errors are you getting? The line `subitems=v.SubMenUs;` looks a bit strange to me; maybe it should say `v.SubMenus`?

Comment: thank you Mr.Namida Aneskans it is working it thankalot my friend nice coding